# Extjs - 4.1 Extending controller from a different Package

Tags: extjs4.1

I have huge application. 
I would have a common folder with common extjs files across multiple extensions.
Extension folder will extend basic view from common and add its own components.
My application structure would be

common
-app
--model
--view
--store
--controller
---CommonController.js(controller file)

extension1
-app
--model
--view
--store
--controller
---Extension1Controller.js (This should extend CommonController.js)
app.js

app.js

Code:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'extjs/ux');
Ext.Loader.setPath('commonapp', '/common/app');
Ext.require([
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.tree.*'

]);


Ext.application({
    name: 'NSM',
    appFolder: '/extension1/app',

    controllers: [

        'Extension1Controller'

    ],
    launch: function() {

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        layout: 'fit',
        renderTo:'contentContainer',

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel'

            }
        ]
    });

    }
});
```

Extension1Controller.js

```
Ext.define('NSM.controller.Extension1Controller', {
    extend: 'commonapp.controller.CommonController', //Extending the controller from common






    init: function() {
        //this.getWPPolicyStoreStore().addListener('write',this.finishedLoading, this);

        console.log("in sample controller");
    }


    });
```

But extending throws following error

**Uncaught Error: The following classes are not declared even if their files have been loaded: 'commonapp.controller.CommonController'. Please check the source code of their corresponding files for possible typos: '/common/app/controller/CommonController.js**

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

please replace extend config with 'Ext.app.Controller' instead of 'commonapp.controller.CommonController' . Because extend you are specifying what class are you going to extend. To solve your problem, just add that controller('commonapp.controller.CommonController') in Ext.application block as part of another controllers.

Thanks.